# What application performance management tools are available for a restricted infrastructure?

Tags: .net, webserver, web-analytics, web-performance

We are supporting several .NET applications for a government client and need a way to monitor performance for these applications. However the government restricts access to external internet access from this web server. Most of these tools like [New Relic APM](http://newrelic.com/application-monitoring) require sending information thru the internet/cloud, are there tools that work without accessing the cloud?

Comment: What kind of performance are they looking to monitor? Server uptime? Client-side page load time?

Comment: User capacity, response time, downtime, bottlenecks, etc...

Comment: like Google analytics, but private...no sending info to a cloud platform...but internally

Comment: Server monitoring too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at APM tools such as Dynatrace AppMon & UEM. Dynatrace can be deployed on-premise which means that all your data stays within your data center.
I suggest you watch my youtube tutorial on what dynatrace is and how it works. In that webinar I also instrument a .NET App to show how easy it is to set it up and capture data: [What is Dynatrace AppMon & UEM and how does it work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ycuNlYUl9E&list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6&index=1)

Comment: This tool seems to have all the features that we need and surprisingly comes with a free license! The others that I have reviewes had cost up to $10k. What's your review of the product and any disadvantages compared to others?

Comment: Any specific features that had the highest value for your client?

Comment: I am biased - so - I think you have to make up your own mind on which features are of high value. If you have a look at the youtube video I linked to you see what I think the main value prop is of dynatrace. I love it as a developer as it gives me extremely rich data. NOt only on my local machine or in CI - but also in load testing and in production. But as I said: check it out yourself. Also compare it with other tools in the space and pick the tool that makes best sense for your app and env.

Comment: Apologies, I just noticed your name from the video :(  Thank you for the video and the great tool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the performance you're looking for is client-side web performance, you could use a private instance of WebPageTest.

WPT is a free, open-source tool that uses real browsers to load a web page and record its performance. There is a public version of the tool at [webpagetest.org](http://webpagetest.org). To test pages on a private network, you will need to install a private instance of the tool with a front-end to configure the tests and agent browsers to run the tests. For documentation you can check out the [official WPT docs](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/private-instances) or the book I co-authored, [Using WebPageTest](http://usingwpt.com).

The WPT tool just gives you ad-hoc performance results for a given page. To set up proper monitoring, you'll need a bit more. There are a few existing synthetic monitoring tools available like Speed Curve and Show Slow. You could definitely grow your own monitoring tool from scratch too (it's pretty easy). The basic steps would be scheduling preconfigured tests to run regularly and charting the results. There is an [API](https://sites.google.com/a/webpagetest.org/docs/advanced-features/webpagetest-restful-apis) that will help you with both of these things.

Comment: I think we need a combination of google analytics which tracks visitor requests, response time, downtime, visited pages and overall performance plus a web portal  to analyze the capture data into graphs or reporting?